# Replacing Delimiter in MCONCAT formula

Tags: excel, delimiter, array-formulas

I'm using the MCONCAT formula (with success & help from others) to create a single string of multiple attachment names to associate them with a single record # (I am converting data from a legacy system to another by way of flat files and a data loader).

An example: | Contract 1 | filename.pdf, filename2.doc |

However, when the first load was run, records that had a comma in the name error-ed out because the data loader is viewing the comma as the break between files. After some research, we decided to use '@' as the delimiter between multiple files in a cell. Now I am stuck trying to substitute the comma delimiters in my MCONCAT formula with '@' and have been fruitless so far.

Here is the code as I am using it now:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(MCONCAT(IF($A$2:$A$11133=$D2,", "&$B$2:$B$11133,"")),", ","",1)
```

Is this possible to do? If so, how & maybe (if not asking to much) a short explanation so I can fully understand.

An example of the hopeful solution: | Contract 1 | filename.pdf @ filename2.doc |

Comment: What is your original `MCONCAT` formula? Is your table 2 columns, "contract #" and "file list"?

Comment: @NickSlash that is my original MCONCAT formula (lifted it off of another tutorial and changed look-ups and arrays to get it to work). Yes, my table is those two columns exactly.

Comment: Is your data just text? (no formula) also, is it a dynamic list (ie: you generate it) or do you want to do a one-off fix to change the separator in your data.

Comment: @NickSlash data is just text and I'm looking for a one off fix to change the separator in my data because I will be using it on different lists

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the complexity of the filenames with commas in, you might be able to do what you want simply using the Find & Select / Replace feature of excel.

Please use a *copy* of your workbook if you try anything suggested.

If your separator is *always* `[list item][comma][space][list item]` and none of your `[list item(s)]` contain `[comma][space]` then using a "find what" term of ", " (note the space!) and "replace with" term of "@ ", Using `[at][space]` instead of `[space][at][space]` is probably better, and selecting the column containing the list should fix your problem.

A VBA solution is possible but it would probably be more effort than its worth. You might need to write lots of rules telling it how to split and join stuff, and end up with it still not being perfect.

While doing it manually might not be a fun idea, you could use something like "text to columns" to split your list then look over the results and fix the errors then re-join using your new delimiter.

Comment: That is one of the main issues, I have [comma][space] in certain file names. I am going to try some of your suggestions on a copy of my workbook.

Comment: @SteveMac do your files have specific file extensions? (could you list all of them)

Comment: The majority are .pdf, .msg & .doc. I tried a few of your suggestions and unfortunately I have lots of items with both [comma][space] and [space][commma][space] in the item name. Do you think its possible to just place the'@' in my MCONCAT formula?

Comment: I don't see where it fits in. You said your list was just text. If your list is the result of that formula then yes, changing it to use `@` instead would work.